# How to make mui button size larger than life?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, button, material-ui

The current MUI button supports `size` prop values as the following

- `small`
- `medium`
- `large`

While this is convenient, I wish I could pass the height and width into the `style` prop and customize the size like

```
        <Button
          variant="contained"
          size="large"
          onClick={onDownloadButtonClick}
          style={{
            width: '30em',
            height: '40em' // call it humonguous
          }}
        >
          Download
        </Button>
```

Any idea how I can achieve something like this?

Comment: Can't you do that with `style={{width,height}}`?

Comment: @NearHuscarl nope.

Comment: @AakashVerma what's wrong with [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-uebpe?file=/demo.tsx) approach?

Comment: @NearHuscarl whoa, I never noticed I can pass values without px. let me try. thanks

Comment: @NearHuscarl It works. Can you post it as an answer?

Comment: @AakashVerma by default, number values in `CssProperties` use `px` unit so `20` will be converted to `'20px'`. You only have to use string when you use other unit (`%`, `rem`...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting Material-UI `Button` size (`'small'` | `'large'`) [only changes](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/47db37bebe27538161e353ff1de4a70d8a47daee/packages/material-ui/src/Button/Button.js#L216-L217) the `font-size` and `padding` of a button. If you want to make a button extra large by overriding `width` and `height`, you can easily do that by inlining css style on said `Button`:

```js
<Button variant="contained" style={{ width: 500, height: 300 }}>
  Default
</Button>
```

[image: Edit 66817860/how-to-make-mui-button-size-larger-than-life]

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
 <Button style={{maxWidth: '30em', maxHeight: '40em', minWidth: '30em', minHeight: '40em'}}/>
```

Comment: Dude, don't copy from https://stackoverflow.com/a/51039757/5924738. Instead, share the link as a comment to my question so that I can close my question.

Comment: Not that, that question solves my answer but if it did, I would close my question.